# Why to use Apache beam spark runner if we can directly use Apache spark?

Tags: apache-spark, etl, apache-beam

I was reading about apache beam. Gone through various runners in apache beam. But i am wondering why should someone use apache beam with spark runner if he can directly use apache spark?

Answer (score 0):

Because of `Apache Beam` is **unified**, **portable**, and **extensible** that implement batch and streaming data processing jobs that run on any execution engine. It's meaning that you can write just one code for both **streaming** and **batch** jobs without any dependency on the execution platform

Comment: Thanks Hossein Torabi. What do you mean by "execution engine" here?   Is it dataflow, spark, splink, etc. ?

Comment: Hossein means that you can run the same code in many execution engines (runners), for example Cloud Dataflow, Spark, Flink, Apex..

Comment: Athough in theory the portability promise indeed free you from learning different SDK, in practice not all runners are equivalent. The Spark one (in Dataset version) does not implement most of the windows and triggers concepts from the Beam programming model. Here is the compatibility matrix: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/